# AJAX Call from multiple selects

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, autosave

This is a continuation of a previous post, I am super new to AJAX and as such keep hitting a brick wall. Anways I have the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#view1, #view2, #view3, #view4, #view5, #view6, #view7, #view8, #view9, #view10, #view11, #view12, #view13, #view14, #view15, #view16, #view17, #view18').on( 'change', 'select', function( ) {                            
        var statusVal = $(this).val();
          var job_id = $(this).prop('id');
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "saveStatus.php",
                   data: { statusType : statusVal, jobID: job_id },
                   cache : false,
                   success: function(data) {
                    $('#view1').load('jobs.php #view1', function() {});
                    $('#view2').load('jobs.php #view2', function() {});
                    $('#view3').load('jobs.php #view3', function() {});
                    $('#view4').load('jobs.php #view4', function() {});
                    $('#view5').load('jobs.php #view5', function() {});
                    $('#view6').load('jobs.php #view6', function() {});
                    $('#view7').load('jobs.php #view7', function() {});
                    $('#view8').load('jobs.php #view8', function() {});
                    $('#view9').load('jobs.php #view9', function() {});
                    $('#view10').load('jobs.php #view10', function() {});
                    $('#view11').load('jobs.php #view11', function() {});  
                    $('#view12').load('jobs.php #view12', function() {});   
                    $('#view13').load('jobs.php #view13', function() {});   
                    $('#view14').load('jobs.php #view14', function() {});   
                    $('#view15').load('jobs.php #view15', function() {});   
                    $('#view16').load('jobs.php #view16', function() {});   
                    $('#view17').load('jobs.php #view17', function() {});   
                    $('#view18').load('jobs.php #view18', function() {});   
                   }
        })
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now I have multiple select statements each in a div with the is view1-18, so 18 divs each with a select statement, It works by auto saving the value from the select to my DB, this works great however **I am sure this is poorly written code so my first question is help to get it formatted properly**.

My second question is what if now i wanted to add two selects in each div and each one getting saved to a different DB field. Below is my select code:

```
    <select name="status" id="<?php echo str_pad($job->job_id, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>">
      <option value=''>--Select--</option>
      <option value='Job Approved' <?php if($job->job_schedulestatus == 'Job Approved') echo 'selected'; ?> >Jobs Approved to Print Internally</option>
      <option value='To Artwork' <?php if($job->job_schedulestatus == 'To Artwork') echo 'selected'; ?> >To Artwork</option>   
    </select>
```

I thought about just adding another and calling it "status2" and creating a duplicate AJAX call and renaming anything where it says status to status2 , this however doesn't work and I have no idea where to go. I have also created a saveStatus2.php which will have the code to insert into the new field.

Any guidance/Help will be greatly appreciated

Ian

Comment: Do you need to update very view every time a select is changed? Or do you need to just update the current view when a select is changed?

Comment: Yes I need to update every view holds information based on what value is saved and by changing one could mean that 2 views will change.

Comment: Can you add classes to your views?

Comment: Already have class's. The comment below seems to smallen the code. I now need to beable to have 2 selects in each div, but can only change the name of each not the id and save each one into a different field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a little suspect to me - mainly because what I see is the "ajax inception" thing going on. Remember $.load() is also an ajax function, so you are calling multiple .load events as the callback to the main ajax event.

Is there a way to consolidate that into a single Ajax call, as in the first wrapper ajax you have and then let PHP set all the selects for you?

If you have to iterate through each select, I may go this route to make it a little cleaner:

```
for(var i=1; i<19; i++)
{
  $('#view'+i).load('jobs.php#view'+i); //empty callback not needed here as well..
}
```

Comment: That works great thankyou, any ideas on how I can now get it to work with two selects?

Comment: Assign a class to your select like class="select1", same thing for 2. Have the select number be in the id, like id="view1", etc. then, set up a change listener for the selects. Using the class selector in jquery will bind this to all selects with that class. such as $('.select1').on('click', function(){ id = $(this).prop('id') .... }) and then make the .load call within that same callback...

Comment: sorry, that should be .on('change',... not 'click'.

Comment: Using a class on select and calling then in a AJAX statement and then creating a new statement for the second one seems to work. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this...

```
// cache the views
var views = $('.view');

$('#view_wrapper').on('change', 'select', function() {
    var statusVal = $(this).val();
    var job_id = $(this).prop('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveStatus.php",
        data: { statusType : statusVal, jobID: job_id },
        cache : false,
        success: function(data) {
            $(views).eatch(function() {
                var view_id = $(this).prop('id');
                $('#'+view_id).load('jobs.php#'+view_id);
            });
        }
    });
});
```